# case statement alignment and cleanup in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Solved a business requirement using a case statement. The case statement is same across multiple date attributes. I am aware that case statement works on single attribute at a time and to make it repetitive using dynamic sql but we dont want to use dynamic sql.
is there a way to simplify the case statement so that at least it looks repetitive and easier to understand. Any ideas?

```
CASE 
   WHEN Status IN ('Denied','Partial Approval') and NotificationDate <> '1900-01-01' AND NotificationDate < Requestdate THEN 'Error'
   WHEN Status IN ('Denied','Partial Approval') and NotificationDate >= RequestDate THEN 
   CASE

            when Type in ('Non-Urgent Preservice','Non-Urgent Concurrent') AND DateDiff(d,RequestDate,NotificationDate) <= 15 then  'Y'         
            when Type = 'Post Service' AND DateDiff(d,RequestDate,NotificationDate) <= 30 then 'Y'    
            when Type = 'Urgent Preservice' AND DateDiff(d,RequestDate,NotificationDate) <= 3 then 'Y'
            when Type = 'Urgent Concurrent' AND DateDiff(d,RequestDate,NotificationDate) <= 3 then 'Y'  
   ELSE 'N'
   END
ELSE 
CASE WHEN Status IN ('Denied','Partial Approval') and NotificationDate IS NULL THEN 
   CASE

            when Type in ('Non-Urgent Preservice','Non-Urgent Concurrent') AND DateDiff(d,RequestDate, getdate()) > 15 then  'N'
            when Type = 'Post Service' AND DateDiff(d,RequestDate, getdate()) > 30 then 'N'
            when Type = 'Urgent Preservice' AND DateDiff(d,RequestDate, getdate()) > 3 then 'N'
            when Type = 'Urgent Concurrent' AND DateDiff(d,RequestDate, getdate()) > 3 then 'N'
   ELSE ''
   END
ELSE 'N/A'
```

Comment: Case statements can be moved to the where clause of a subquery.  If it's feasible you could GROUP BY the date ranges instead of repeating everything else by date range.

Answer (score 1):

For the repetitive part, you can use `cross apply` to give the expression a name:

```
select . . .,
      (case when Status in ('Denied', 'Partial Approval') and NotificationDate <> '1900-01-01' and NotificationDate < Requestdate 
            then 'Error'
            when Status in ('Denied', 'Partial Approval') and NotificationDate >= RequestDate 
            then v.y_or_n 
            else 'N'
       end)
from t cross apply
     (values (case when Type in ('Non-Urgent Preservice', 'Non-Urgent Concurrent') and DateDiff(day, RequestDate, NotificationDate) <= 15 
                   then  'Y'         
                   when Type = 'Post Service' and DateDiff(day, RequestDate, NotificationDate) <= 30
                   then 'Y'    
                   when Type = 'Urgent Preservice' and DateDiff(day, RequestDate, NotificationDate) <= 3
                   then 'Y'
                   when Type = 'Urgent Concurrent' and DateDiff(day, RequestDate, NotificationDate) <= 3
                   then 'Y'  
                   else 'N'
              end)
         ) v(y_or_n)
```

Comment: What if I want To use other date attributes which needs to be used instead of notification date?? Do I have again cross apply for new date??

Comment: @user1672315k . . . I don't understand your question.  You can take any expression that would be in the `select` and include it in the `values()` clause with a name -- and it will be evaluated only once.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Case when does allow an option on just a single field, but you can also do based on conditions such as

```
case 
   when ( SomeCondition And AnotherCondition AND Third ) 
      then 'This Answer'
   when (TotallyDifferent OR ( SomeOther AND AlsoThis)) 
      then 'Second Answer'
   when (AnyOther And AnotherDifferent) 
      then 'Third'
   else 
      'Neither of other conditions' 
end
```

So, you could just keep adding "WHEN/THEN" conditions.  They may get lengthy as you do have conditions of

```
Status IN ('Denied','Partial Approval')
```

which is used in multiple.  It could be repeated within each WHEN portion.  Now, just consider, whichever WHEN condition qualifies first WINS, so specific order is important.